# Configuring ASP.Net application to support muliti tenant using Azure AD account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I created an ASP.NET MVC application and configured authentication with Azure AD using OpenIDConnect. I created a user in one Azure AD and added the same in another Azure AD with right privilege. 
I store the claims returned after the Azure AD authentication, in ADAL cache. I use this claim(token cache)to call various Azure Service Management API.

```
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Password"]);
            // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's EF DB
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(
                string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Authority"], organizationId), new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserUniqueName));
            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AzureResourceManagerIdentifier"], credential,
                new UserIdentifier(signedInUserUniqueName, UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId));
var token= result.AccessToken;
```

I have configured my application to support multitenant by adding the following in my Account/SignIn controller/action.

```
 public void SignIn(string directoryName = "common")
        {
            // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Environment.Add("Authority", string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Authority"] + "OAuth2/Authorize", directoryName));

                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                   OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
```

Now, upon successful signin, the claims that are returned, belong to the original Azure AD in which the user is initially registered in. Thus, the claims used to call management api for any other Azure AD, in which the user is also added, does not work and throws exception as "Acquire Token failed to  obtain token".

I added the name of the other Azure AD to the variable  "directoryName" on runtime. This time the claims obtained worked for both the Azure AD.

How to get the SSO for multitenant application, without explicitly mentioning the Azure AD name while signing-in, which will provide me with the claims that can work for all the Azure AD in which the user is registered.

Kindly suggest.
Thanks in advance,
Rahul

Comment: Dumb question: Have you configured the application to be multi-tenant?

Comment: Yes I did so. It is configured as multitenant. 
User  "abc@abcdef.onmicrosoft.com" is originally in "abcdef.onmicrosoft.com" AD. With the same user name, the user is registered in "xyz.onmicrosoft.com" AD with tag "Source from: Another Azure AD".
Upon signing in the Azure Portal, user is able to see both the directories.
But, when the user uses application's Azure Sign-in, Probably the claims belong to only one directory. It is this reason that, it fails for the other directory.
How to achieve SSO with multitenant configuration.
Guide please.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your parameter signedInUserUniqueName is, I often write like this to get accesstoken:

```
 AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + Properties.Settings.Default.TenantID);
            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: Properties.Settings.Default.ClientID, clientSecret: Properties.Settings.Default.ClientSecretKey);
            AuthenticationResult result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);
            var token = result.AccessToken;
```

Comment: This works when the application is already added in the Tenant whose TenantID you are referencing in the code.
For a multitenant application, application gets added in the Azure Tenant on the grant of the singned in user of that Tenant. 

The issue is with the sing-in of the user who belongs to multiple Azure AD. How to get claims, that support multiple Azure AD graph api calls made on behalf of that signed in user.

At present, the claims obtained are tenant specific. But, if you are part of multiple Azure AD why can't you get the claims which supports multiple AD you are registered in.